# R : how to name String without creating an object

Tags: r

I want to just name these strings `"Agra"` and `"huge"` as `place` and `adjective` in the simplest way possible.

First I tried this

```
> args <- list(place <- "Agra", adjective <- "huge")
> args[[1]]
[1] "Agra"
but
> args[["place"]]
NULL
and
> place
[1] "Agra"
```

here only place object is created but the string is not named

whereas

```
> args <- list(place = "Agra", adjective = "huge")
here 
>args[[1]]
"Agra"
> args[["place"]]
[1] "Agra"
> place
[1] "Agra"
```

Although the second one works but objects are still created. why there is a difference in the outputs of the two methods? how can I give names without creating objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `<-` and `=` are not the same. For (just about) every purpose **except when used inside a function call**, `<-` and `=` are the same. If you want to pass a named argument, you *have* to use `=` not `<-`. `myFunction(X <- expression)` will evaluate `expression` and save the result into the (global) variable `X`, and put the result as the first (**unnamed**) argument to `myFunction`. Contrast to `myFunction(X = expression)` which pass the expression as the **named** `X` argument to `myFunction` and will *not* create a (global) variable `X`.

My explanation is a little garbled - I highly recommend reading `?'<-'` (the helpfile for `<-` and `=`) which is clearer.

---

In the first one:

```
args <- list(place <- "Agra", adjective <- "huge")
```

R evaluates `place <- "Agra"` in the global environment, which returns `"Agra"`. It also evaluates `adjective <- "huge"` in the global environment similarly, returning "huge". Then it places the results ("Agra" and "huge") into the `list()` call as *unnamed arguments*, so essentially what you are doing is

```
place <- "Agra"
adjective <- "huge"
args <- list("Agra", "huge")
```

That is why you get global variables, and the `args` list has no names. If this is what you want, you should use the long form not the short form to write it. Using the first form could lead to unexpected or confusing side-effects.

In the second option

```
args <- list(place = "Agra", adjective = "huge")
```

it is simply passing the *named* argument "place" with value "Agra", and the named argument "adjective" with value "huge". Since `list()` uses argument names as list names, that's why you get a named list. Also, this will *not* create global variables `place` and `adjective`.

Comment: Another way to phrase one of those key concepts, "`=` acts as an assignment operator if and only if it is used outside of a function call"

Comment: just one doubt, in the second method if `place` is not a global variable then how it is accessible outside function call?

Comment: @Ankit it isn't - it's still there from your first line. If you put `rm(list=ls())` in between to clear the workspace, you can confirm the second line will not  create any variables.